# Filtering rows and columns with respect to one column data

Tags: python, pandas

How to select the data (highlighted) based on the values of the first column. I mean I need to select data starting and ending with specific time as I don't know the data in `S08`, `S09` and so on.

After this I will take the `mean()` of first 100 values of each column and then so on.

```
g3=df.loc[(df.timeInterval>=171) & (df.timeInterval<=174) & (df.timeInterval>=181) & (df.timeInterval<=184) & (df.timeInterval>=191) & (df.timeInterval<=194) & (df.timeInterval>=201) & (df.timeInterval<=204),['S08','S09','S41']]
g3
```

[image]

Comment: what you mean first 100 and so on ? 0-99 100-199 200-299?

Comment: Yes. After selecting the data as asked, i will need to calculate mean of  0-99 100-199 200-299...

Comment: Simply put, you can't "highlight" a csv file and have pandas extract that data only. Figure out the indices, slice out the data, and perform your analysis.

Comment: Highlighting is just to ask you which data i need to extract. And of course i have only timeInterval information (ist column).

Comment: You'll get more responses if you copy and paste data, then people can copy it into a DataFrame easily

Comment: @AlexS ok. do you mean i should upload the csv file ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble getting pandas indexing to work as expected, but do you mean something like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.random.rand(10, 2)), columns = ['timeInterval', 'value'])

df2 = df['value'][df.timeInterval >= 0.3][df.timeInterval <= 0.7]
df2
```